# Grep string from map object

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to extract each username value in clients object and store in array (bash). However, grep failed to match even through matched in regex101.com

```
//a.txt
username = "fakeuservalue"

clients = [
  {
    username = "user1"
  },
  {
    username = "user2"
  }
]


x=$(cat a.txt | grep -e 'username\s+=\s+\"(.*)\"')
echo $x
```

Any clues? I'm also try to add another check on "clients" object so that skip retrieve "fakeuservalue".

Comment: If your `clients` object is json (what posted in the question is not a valid json),
then you can use tools such as jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that gives you a lot of power for filtering and accessing values in JSONs

for example, the following will output all the "username" values:
`clients='[{"username": "user1"}, {"username": "user2"}]'`
`jq '.[].username' <<< $clients`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
x=$(sed -n '/^clients = \[/,/^]$/s/.*username *= *"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' a.txt)
```

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/KkFoBc):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='username = "fakeuservalue"

clients = [
  {
    username = "user1"
  },
  {
    username = "user2"
  }
]'
sed -n '/^clients = \[/,/^]$/s/.*username *= *"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
user1
user2
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Extract username values using `grep`

```
grep -oP '(?<=username = ")[^"]*' a.txt
```

#### 2. Assign username values into array `arr1`.

```
readarray -t arr1 <<< $(grep -oP '(?<=username = ")[^"]*' a.txt)
```

#### 3. Print all array `arr1` elements

```
printf "%s\n" ${arr1[@]}
```

#### 4. Print first and last elements in array `arr1` having 3 elements

```
echo "${arr1[0]}"
echo "${arr[2]}"
```

Comment: thx for details explanation.. grep -oP options, where P option not a valid arg in my zsh?